# Google Sheets Query+Importrange with where clause referencing data column of the resultant sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

So I have 2 google sheets(workbooks), A and B.
B is a master with 20 column of information, 2 of which are firstname and lastname.
In A i have only 2 columns filled firstname and lastname. I need to get data from 5 other column for each row in A.

---

I have the following query which works:

### **=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvDr1nki65j4KC3PKY8Cd_dxZFL7emkIHtK4CCMQwkk/edit#gid=664869195","Form Responses 1!A:K"),"select Col5, Col6, Col10, Col11 where Col2 contains 'John' and  Col3 contains 'Doe'")**

---

Replacing with cell value also works as below.

**=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvDr1nki65j4KC3PKY8Cd_dxZFL7emkIHtK4CCMQwkk/edit#gid=664869195","Form Responses 1!A:K"),"select Col5, Col6, Col10, Col11 where Col2 contains '"&Housing!A2&"' and  Col3 contains '"&Housing!B2&"'")**

---

---

However when I try to make it generic it DOES NOT WORK.

=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvDr1nki65j4KC3PKY8Cd_dxZFL7emkIHtK4CCMQwkk/edit#gid=664869195","Form Responses 1!A:K"),"select Col5, Col6, Col10, Col11 where Col2 contains '"&Housing!A&"' and  Col3 contains '"&Housing!B&"'")

Can someone please tell me how do I get this work?

---

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don’t think the query function is meant to be used in the way you are trying to use it :(

I would suggest splitting up the operation and looking into using some helper functions & `XLOOKUP()`.

For example, you might:

1. Have a separate tab where you use IMPORTRANGE() to import your data.
2. Add an array formula to create a column on the far left (let’s say col A that joins the first & last names together to make a key (CAUTION: assumes no one has the same first & last name)
3. In another tab, Grab all the unique names using using `=UNIQUE(ImportportRangeTab!A:A)`
4. Use BYROW() and XLOOKUP() to grab all the columns of data from the imported range tab that correspond with the list of names